Synapse json flatten step parsing issue
I have a payload that is similar to the below that needs to be flattened using Synapse. COMPLEXSECTION1 is parsed as a complex type but COMPLEXSECTION2 which is also a complex is not being parsed as a complex type . but as a string . I attempted the ParseJSON step but it din't work either . Need to flatten the COMPLEXSECTION2 . Any suggestions ?
{
"SIMPLESECTION1": "1234",
"COMPLEXSECTION1": [
    {
        "VAR1": "RESULT",
        "VAR2": "RESULT"
    },
    {
        "VAR1": "RESULT1",
        "VAR2": "RESULT2"
    }
],
"COMPLEXSECTION2": {
    "SEC1": [
        {
            "VAR1": "RESULT",
            "VAR2": "RESULT"
        },
        {
            "VAR1": "RESULT",
            "VAR2": "RESULT"
        }
    ],
    "SEC2": [
        {
            "VAR1": "RESULT",
            "VAR2": "RESULT"
        }
    ]
}

}

can you provide the expected output details

I tried the below approach :
I used a sample JSON like this:
{
"SIMPLESECTION1": "1234",
"COMPLEXSECTION1": [
    {
        "VAR1": "RESULT",
        "VAR2": "RESULT"
    },
    {
        "VAR1": "RESULT1",
        "VAR2": "RESULT2"
    }
],
"COMPLEXSECTION2": {
    "SEC1": [
        {
            "VAR1": "RESULT3",
            "VAR2": "RESULT4"
        },
        {
            "VAR1": "RESULT5",
            "VAR2": "RESULT6"
        }
    ],
    "SEC2": [
        {
            "VAR1": "RESULT7",
            "VAR2": "RESULT8"
        }
    ]
}
}

As you mentioned, you have 3 arrays.
I used 3 FLATTEN transformations in a dataflow activity to flatten each array one time.

First Flatten:
Incoming Stream: Source1
Unrolling by COMPLEXSECTION1

Second Flatten:
Incoming Stream: Flatten1
Unrolling by COMPLEXSECTION2.SEC1


Third Flatten:
Incoming Stream: Flatten2
Unrolling by COMPLEXSECTION2_SEC2


Results:

SIMPLESECTION1  COMPLEXSECTION1_VAR1    COMPLEXSECTION1_VAR2    COMPLEXSECTION2_SEC1_VAR1   COMPLEXSECTION2_SEC1_VAR2   COMPLEXSECTION2_SEC2_VAR1   COMPLEXSECTION2_SEC2_VAR2
1234    RESULT  RESULT  RESULT3 RESULT4 RESULT7 RESULT8
1234    RESULT  RESULT  RESULT5 RESULT6 RESULT7 RESULT8
1234    RESULT1 RESULT2 RESULT3 RESULT4 RESULT7 RESULT8
1234    RESULT1 RESULT2 RESULT5 RESULT6 RESULT7 RESULT8




